# SOAP 1.1 Request Fatal Error Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soapenv:Server]

Tags: php, web-services, soap, soap-client, fatal-error

My request is the following:

```
 $client = new SoapClient("http://xxx.de:8080xxxWebService?wsdl", array("trace" => 1, "soap_version" => SOAP_1_1));

$result = $client->__soapCall("calcMietpreis", array('calAbholdatum' => "2015-08-08 11:14:15", 'calRueckgabedatum' => "2015-08-09 11:14:15"));
```

and i got the following Error Message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soapenv:Server] Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method calcMietpreis in /srv/www/htd...
```

I do not know what to do now ... i searched nearly everywhere.

I installed the php extension SOAP and the _getFunctions give me the existing functions. So i think the connection exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like the wsdl isnt supposed to use with PHP instead it is for a Java client.